# Trouble with old video card (NVIDIA GeForce 6600 GT) and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've just assembled a new pc using old hardware. I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 and almost every part works correctly. The issue is relative to the video card (NVIDIA GeForce 6600 GT). I looked for official and unofficial drivers (nouveau), but every my attempt failed. Actually I can see without problem everything on my screen but at low resolution (1280x1024). I'd like to reach 1920x1080 but it seems impossible to install officials (tried with 304 version with and without dkms) and unofficials (nouveau drivers lets me to reach 1920*1080 but images, text and everything are messy on the screen).
Any ideas?

Ty in advice

Comment: your use of *official* and *unofficial* make little sense to me; `nouveau` is the official open-source driver supported by nvidia, but there are closed-source drivers available as options.  The closed source could also be referred to as proprietary and other terms, but that doesn't relate to official (nvidia do help support nouveau and have since 2013 - https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/FAQ.html#index7h3)

Comment: Yes, you right. I used probably those words incorrectly, however it seems you understand perfectly the problem. Now, do you have some suggestions to share to solve the situation or do you want just open a discussion about the right meaning of the words? Ty

Comment: Using the correct terminology is important for good communication. You couldn't have installed 304 because it isn't compatible with the current kernels. Whatever you did made things worse, obviously. Please check my answer below. Nouveau is indeed your only option other than replacing the ancient hardware. In Windows 10 the situation is even worse as it would be running with a generic driver.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll have to run with *nouveau* and accept its performance as is.

There's no other solution because the last Nvidia proprietary driver that supports your card is 304 and 304 can't be installed with any kernel newer than the one present in the first release of Ubuntu 16.04. So, yes, that was a long time ago.

You may try Ubuntu flavors other than the standard Gnome, like Xubuntu or Lubuntu. The current standard Ubuntu is too much for hardware of such vintage.

Comment: Ty a lot for your explaination. Reading your answer drive me to consider a different distro. I'm going to check Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem with an old laptop I use for testing. It has NVIDIA Geforce 8300 graphics hardware.

I was able to patch and compile the 304 driver on Ubuntu 18.04 using the procedure found here

- https://adufray.com/blog/

The discussion on the launchpad bug was helpful to me while I was trying to get it to work

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1737750

I've since wiped and reinstalled on that laptop a couple of times, so unfortunately I don't have it available to reference on this problem any more :(  I think even this quit working with the 5.X.X-XX kernels though.

Comment: Yes, you right. I tried to follow the guide about patching on 18.04 version but, unfortunaly, it doesn't work. Ty a lot for your answer